# Does model evaluation during training affect final accuracy in PyTorch?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, pytorch, data-science

During a simple training loop for PyTorch a strange effect was observed.
If the evaluation function is called or not seems to have effects on the final performance of the model.

We train on the CIFAR10 using a very simple MLP model and Adam with 10 training epochs.

We try two Main loops:

1. After the end of each training epoch we measure the accuracy of validation set
2. We calculate the validation only once at the end of all training.

We show the difference in code here below:

Main Loop 1:

```
# Main Loop 1
num_epochs = 10 
print(f"num_epochs: {num_epochs}")

for epoch in range(num_epochs):  # loop over the dataset multiple times
    print(f"\nStart Epoch {epoch}")
    
    model.train()
    
    train_loss, train_accuracy = training_epoch(trainloader,optimizer,model,criterion)
    print(f"Training Loss: {train_loss:.3f} - Training Accuracy: {train_accuracy:.3f}")

    model.eval()
    
    with torch.no_grad():
        val_loss, val_accuracy = val_epoch(testloader, model, criterion)
    print(f"Val Loss: {val_loss:.3f} - Val Accuracy: {val_accuracy:.3f}")

print('Finished Training')
```

Main Loop 2:

```
# Main Loop 2
num_epochs = 10 
print(f"num_epochs: {num_epochs}")

for epoch in range(num_epochs):  # loop over the dataset multiple times
    print(f"\nStart Epoch {epoch}")
    
    model.train()
    
    train_loss, train_accuracy = training_epoch(trainloader,optimizer,model,criterion)
    print(f"Training Loss: {train_loss:.3f} - Training Accuracy: {train_accuracy:.3f}")
    
model.eval()    
with torch.no_grad():
    val_loss, val_accuracy = val_epoch(testloader, model, criterion)
print(f"Val Loss: {val_loss:.3f} - Val Accuracy: {val_accuracy:.3f}")

print('Finished Training')
```

Though there shouldn't be any change, the final performance of model change.

1. Val Loss: 1.526 - Val Accuracy: 0.523
2. Val Loss: 1.501 - Val Accuracy: 0.528

Of course for reproducibility, we set all seeds. Moreover, this effect can already be observed at the beginning of the second training epoch.

I share the entire code as a Colab notebook:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1BODeKHZmcT8lH3r2bxYVHNR2KOpT9O9Y?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

The observed difference would be due to variance because of stochasticity in the optimization algorithm. The evaluation you perform has no effect on the model's weights.

Also in the link you provided, you are re-initializing a `SimpleMLP` on both experiments. Since the module's weights get instantiated randomly the inference will naturally yield different results.

Comment: Hi @Ivan. To avoid the effect of stochasticity I set the seeds at the beginning so I am not clear what you mean. Moreover, if you execute the same code multiple times there is not stochasticity.

Comment: If you are using GPU to perform the computation you will still have stochasticity because of the randomness of some algorithms which is true even after having set the seeds.

Comment: I'm not sure if you properly seeded everything either, I ran both loops on cpu only instances and neither one gave the expected result.

Comment: @figbar I believe OP initializes the model twice. See my edit above...

Comment: Hi @figbar. Thank you for your interest in the matter. I would be interested to have a code that given the seeds can allow reproducibility. Any advice to block this stochasticity ? Clearly, in the research a code/model is expected to be reproducible, therefore there should be a way to avoid this.

Comment: This is not possible when using GPUs. The only way to ensure reproducibility is to measure the variance of your experiments by training multiple the same model multiple times with different seeds.